# WordPress in page variable scope

Tags: php, wordpress, variables

I am confused with variable scope in WordPress.
i.e. will variable defined in one file be available
in another file in the same theme? i.e.

Files Location:
custom theme

Scenario 1

```
file: functions.php
line 1: <?php 
line 2:  $foo = 'value';

file: footer.php
line 1: <?php 
line 2:  echo $foo; //undefined?
```

Scenario 2

```
file: header.php
line 1: <?php 
line 2:  $foo = 'value';

file: footer.php
line 1: <?php 
line 2:  echo $foo; //undefined?
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make a variable available throughout the theme, you will need to set it a global variable. As per your example, that variable set will only be available to that specific function.

Just a few notes here on globals

- If you can, avoid setting your own global variables all together.
- You have to make sure that all variables set within the global scope have unique names. Make use of mixed characters, for instance, use capital letters mixed with lower case letters and add a few numbers in between
- Names should also not just be unique, but they should not be easily recreated. For instance, a global name like `$dog` is unique, but this name can very easily be used in another plugin which will clash with your global variable name. To make this very unique, use the theme name in conjuction with the variable name, something like `$mytheme_dog`

From your example, you can try something like this

```
file: functions.php
line 1: <?php 
line 2: global $foo;
line 3:  $foo = 'value';

file: footer.php
line 1: <?php 
line 2: global $foo;
line 3:  echo $foo;
```

Answer (score 0):

Variables can be access if treated as global variable. For example:

If you assign a variable in `functions.php`

```
$test_variable = 'this is test';
```

In `header.php`, you can do like this.

```
global $test_variable;
echo $test_variable;
```